# R Shiny - Refresh app session (shinyjs.reset) when navigating to a specific navbarPage tab

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

My app progresses through a series of panels, where the user can progress to the next panel by clicking an action button. I would like the entire app to refresh when navigating to another tab. This means the user will start back at the first in a series of panels, and any widget inputs will have been reset.

I have provided the panels with id's, and am attempting to refresh the app using

```
    shinyjs.reset = function() {history.go(0)}
```

within an

```
    observeEvent()
```

I have also tried resetting the inputs used in the conditional panel selection, and associated widget inputs. Neither of these approaches appears to refresh the app.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

#### Specify the number of pages to use 
NUM_PAGES <- 2

# Define the js method that resets the page 
jsResetCode <- "shinyjs.reset = function() {history.go(0)}"  


# UI
ui <- navbarPage(

  # Call shinyjs
  useShinyjs(),                                          
  extendShinyjs(text = jsResetCode),

  ### Panel 1 ### 
  tabPanel(id = "p1",
           title = "A",
           "Page 1"),

  ### Panel 2 ### 
  tabPanel(id = "p2",
           title = "B",
           div(id = "form",

               ### Sub-panel 1
               conditionalPanel(
                 condition = "input.nextBtn_1 == 0",
                 radioButtons(inputId ="Q1", ("Q1"), choices = c("A", "B"), 
                              selected = character(0)),

                 # Next page button 
                 div(actionButton("nextBtn_1", "Next1 >"))),

               ### Sub-panel 1
               conditionalPanel(
                 # Q1
                 condition = "input.nextBtn_1 == 1 && input.nextBtn_2 == 0",
                 radioButtons(inputId ="Q2", ("Q2"),
                              choices = c("A", "B" , "C"), 
                              selected = character(0)),
                 # Q2
                 radioButtons(inputId ="Q3", ("Q3"),
                              choices = c("A", "B"), 
                              selected = character(0)),

                 # Next page button 
                 div(actionButton("nextBtn_2", "Next2 >")))
           )))


# Server
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Observe event 
      observeEvent(input$p1, {js$reset()})

  # The function for adding the page value
  navPage <- function(input, direction) {
    input <- input + direction
   }

  # When nextBtn is pressed, one is added to page number
  observeEvent(input$nextBtn_1, navPage(input$nextBtn_1, 1))# navPage(1)
  observeEvent(input$nextBtn_2, navPage(input$nextBtn_2, 1))# navPage(1)

}

# run 
shinyApp(server = server, ui = ui)
```

I expect that when the user clicks on the tab "p1" the app refreshes. When the user then navigates back to "p2", they will start on the first panel and no input would be defined for the widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `input$p1` doesn't exist. To find out when a tab is clicked and what tab is clicked, you need to give an `id` to the tab container, and use that id as the input. Also, you mention you want a reset, but the code you're using is a **very hard reset** - it refreshes the page, it's literally the equivalent of pressing the Refresh button. I don't quite understand how the logic you want would work (every time you click on tab 2, the app refreshes and you're back at tab 1 - that means you can never get to tab 2!), but anyway here's what it would look like:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

#### Specify the number of pages to use 
NUM_PAGES <- 2

# Define the js method that resets the page 
jsResetCode <- "shinyjs.reset = function() {history.go(0)}"  


# UI
ui <- navbarPage(
  id = "mytabs",

  # Call shinyjs
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jsResetCode, functions = "reset"),

  ### Panel 1 ### 
  tabPanel(id = "p1",
           title = "A",
           "Page 1"),

  ### Panel 2 ### 
  tabPanel(id = "p2",
           title = "B",
           div(id = "form",

               ### Sub-panel 1
               conditionalPanel(
                 condition = "input.nextBtn_1 == 0",
                 radioButtons(inputId ="Q1", ("Q1"), choices = c("A", "B"), 
                              selected = character(0)),

                 # Next page button 
                 div(actionButton("nextBtn_1", "Next1 >"))),

               ### Sub-panel 1
               conditionalPanel(
                 # Q1
                 condition = "input.nextBtn_1 == 1 && input.nextBtn_2 == 0",
                 radioButtons(inputId ="Q2", ("Q2"),
                              choices = c("A", "B" , "C"), 
                              selected = character(0)),
                 # Q2
                 radioButtons(inputId ="Q3", ("Q3"),
                              choices = c("A", "B"), 
                              selected = character(0)),

                 # Next page button 
                 div(actionButton("nextBtn_2", "Next2 >")))
           )))


# Server
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Observe event 
  observeEvent(input$mytabs, {
    if (input$mytabs == "A") {
      print("tab 1 clicked")
    }
    if (input$mytabs == "B") {
      print("refreshing page")
      js$reset()
    }
  })

  # The function for adding the page value
  navPage <- function(input, direction) {
    input <- input + direction
  }

  # When nextBtn is pressed, one is added to page number
  observeEvent(input$nextBtn_1, navPage(input$nextBtn_1, 1))# navPage(1)
  observeEvent(input$nextBtn_2, navPage(input$nextBtn_2, 1))# navPage(1)

}

# run 
shinyApp(server = server, ui = ui)
```